# Particle fade out by time still working?

Tags: particles

I watched some tutorials about the particle texture fading thing, and every one of them doing the same thing.
Dividing the particles age by lifetime with a color ramp to control the fading out between a texture and a transparent map.
But it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried in multiple scenes with other techniques and nothing. What do I do wrong?  [image: Some things I tried:]

Here is my cleaned blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/cvgu5rfvrtwyh10/Particle.blend/file

---

[Is this in Cycles?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usNXe.jpg)  Sorry I can't tell the old blender design. Also if I select cycles and then select the render view still doesn't seem to work for me. Something in the particle settings that I forgot?

Comment: maybe it doesn't work in Eevee?

Comment: yep, particle info (most of them) only work in cycles

Comment: @moonboots Not just maybe ;) The _Particle Info_ node only works in _Cycles_. And apart from that only with parent particles, not child particles.

Comment: Oh ok then............   ;)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in Eevee because, as pointed out by Chris and Gordon, the *Particle Info* node only works in Cycles.